# Windows Phone shared status task bug

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, share

Well, I don't know if what happens is normal, but I think that is some kind of bug.

I want to use a Shared status task with windows phone, but when I press the button and then I call this task, for some reason appears the following message:

> Set up sharing?
>
> Set up your social networks to share updates with your friends.

If I press Cancel, the Shared task closes.

If I press Set up, then appears a screen which I have to choose between Outlook, Gmail, Hotmail, Facebook, Twitter...

Once I have registered one of them, the message appears again. Is quite annoying :(

The problem is, that I have a Gmail account and 2 hotmail accounts stored in my phone, and I don't understand why this message appears.

Could you tell me what could happen?

The code is the same as the example of MSDN, this:

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the described behavior running the emulator.  But when I loaded the same app onto my real phone, I got the sharing dialog we all want to see.

I think the problem is that the emulator has no accounts set up when you first launch it.  If you could sign in with your Microsoft account (for email, calendar, xbox...) and *then* run the test app, I think it would work.

But I couldn't sign in with my (valid, testing) Microsoft account on the emulator!  I kept getting error 0x8000FFFF when I tried.  I bet this process has been disabled in the emulator.  So I don't know if the test app would have worked if I had been able to complete this.

What I didn't try is to skip signing into a microsoft account and create some other, e.g, a Twitter account, and then run your test app (without letting the emulator close and reopen in the meantime). That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, I used a Twitter account and this annoying message is gone. What I don't understand is why they ask me for any email if they are not considered to use in sharing tasks?

Comment: Since configuring the Twitter acct bypassed the problem, I guess the Sharing task puts up the problematic prompt when it sees there are *no* communication accounts configured yet, which is the case with a brand new phone.

Comment: How did you guys install twitter on emulator? it's not pre-installed and without an account you are not allowed to download apps